# Using SVM with only one feature

Tags: svm, feature-selection

I am doing a parametric study on the performance of SVM w.r.t various input feature sets. In one case, I analyze the performance of SVM using a only one feature at a time (similar to [One-at-a-time approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-factor-at-a-time_method)). I also found an article ([here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8076002)) where the authors analyze each feature's performance with SVM.

My question: ***Is it advisable to use a single feature as input to SVM?***

Answer (score 1):

What SVM does is just to decide the best separating hyperplane. In 1D, it functions very similar to a one-level decision tree, thresholding with something like $x=a$. If your dataset looks like XOR problem in 1D, SVM's result will be bad even if the feature is useful.